# Risk of mold between plywood panel and window

Tags: windows, painting, mold, moisture, plywood

I built a wood panel with a window sill to block the bottom half of a window. The window sash is made of two frames that split the window about halfway. The window and sash are built with a small recess from the interior drywall. I have built the wood panel so it sits flush with the interior drywall, meaning there is a gap of about 4 inches between the wood panel and the window behind.

I primed and painted the wood panel and haven't secured it so it can be removed easily. I think it would look nicer if I secured it and applied some skim coat on the wood panel and silicon joint around the sill, so it looks and feels like the plaster board wall around it. However, I am concerned about moisture/mold build up in the space between the wood panel if I secure the panel and seal it shut with skim coat.

There is glass about 4 inches behind where the plywood is on the picture. What I am trying to do is have a continuous bottom section of the wall shown on the picture so I can install a headboard supported across the whole length.

Do you think mold build up is a risk with this design? Any advice on how to mitigate such build up?

[image]

Comment: "The window sash is made of two frames that split the window about halfway" Is this a standard single/double hung window? Have you insulated between the exterior wall and this interior panel? Why did you buy plywood instead of a piece of drywall which, with some tape & mud and paint would have matched the rest of the wall?

Comment: Window has 2 panels. A fixed one at the bottom, currently behind the interior panel, and a top awning one. Behind the interior panel is a gap of about 4 inches and then the bottom part of the window. I have not insulated that space. Hence my question on risk of moisture build up. I have used plywood rather than drywall, because I am not really experienced with drywall and I am still testing solutions.

Comment: There's glass hiding  behind that piece of plywood? Maybe you'd do better if you tell us _why_ you're covering it up and ask for recommendations about that. There might be a far better alternative that you just haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Yes there is glass about 4 inches behind where the plywood is on the picture. What I am trying to do is have a continuous bottom section of the wall shown on the picture so I can install a headboard supported across the whole length. There are certainly alternative solutions I haven't thought about. Thanks for your help